# C#: Как использовать данные

Tags: c#, ado.net, ado

Мне нужно использовать данные из Экселя. Я добавил "Connection to Database", выбрал тип данным ODBC, указал "Excel" и путь к книге (см. картинку)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно как-то программно использовать эти данные, но я не пойму как.
Подскажите, как я могу к эти данным подключить?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dw70f090(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: @Konst, если быть точным, я не могу написать правильный ConnectionString -  я пробовал копировать его из "XLS", пробовал писать провайдера Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 и пр. Все не то. Какой правильный CS в моем случае?

Comment: выберите правильный вариант на сайте: https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть этот код Вам поможет:

```
string ConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No\";Data Source={0}", "Имя Файла");
// Открываем соединение
DataSet ds = new DataSet("EXCEL");
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
cn.Open();
// Получаем списко листов в файле
DataTable schemaTable = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
// Берем название первого листа
string sheet1 = (string)schemaTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[2];
// Выбираем все данные с листа
string select = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet1);
OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, cn);
ad.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

И далее используете dt(поля, данные можно посмотреть в отладке)...

Comment: Пробовал такое, у меня ругалось на "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0", я вручную все сделал. Спасибо.

Comment: @LeonardBertone, может просто у Вас нет такого провайдера, тогда можно попробовать "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", провайдеры зависят от версии, битности ОС и т.д... так что нужно просто подобрать нужный), но тогда встаёт вопрос совместимости.